# Java - Strange behaviour on PrintStream with custom OutputStream

Tags: java, behavior, outputstream, printstream

I am trying to write a program that redirects System.out to a JTextArea (it doesn't have to be a JTextArea), but when I call System.out.println("Test!") the output to the text area is like so:

```
\n
st!
\n
```

The code for my OutputStream:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class LogOutputStream extends OutputStream
{
    public void write(final int b) throws IOException
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                write0(b);
            }
        });
    }

    public void write(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                write0(b, off, len);
            }
        });
    }

    public void write(final byte[] b)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                write0(b);
            }
        });
    }

    private void write0(int b)
    {
        Document doc = FernflowerGUI.frame.textArea.getDocument();
        try
        {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), String.valueOf((char)b), null);
        }
        catch(BadLocationException impossible)
        {

        }
    }

    private void write0(byte[] b, int off, int len)
    {
        Document doc = FernflowerGUI.frame.textArea.getDocument();
        try
        {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), new String(b, off, len), null);
        }
        catch(BadLocationException impossible)
        {

        }
    }

    private void write0(byte[] b)
    {
        write0(b, 0, b.length);
    }
}
```

The code that creates the PrintStream:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new LogOutputStream(), true);
```

Can anyone please tell me what on Earth is going on?

Comment: That code shows compilation errors here.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: How is the write function called? What are its arguments?

Comment: Is the `\n` shown verbatim? What is the type returned by `getDocument()`, and how is it meant to handle linefeed characters?

Comment: @Andrew Compilation errors? Where?

Comment: @Telthien write is called by the PrintStream, I am not responsible for that

Comment: @Jon The \n is shown as a linebreak, but I'm not familiar with StackOverflow formatting so I just put a \n. Looking through JTextArea's source, the authors themselves don't seem to know what getDocument() will return...

Comment: Lines 42 & 55  `Document doc = FernflowerGUI.frame.textArea.getDocument();` ... `package FernflowerGUI.frame does not exist`

Comment: @Telthien You mean write(b, off, len) calls write0 with 0 for off? I tried that and got the same result.

Comment: So it's actually blank line, then "st!" then another blank line?

Comment: @Jon Yep! I cannot see any possible reason for this, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't thread-safe, basically.

You're accepting a *synchronous* call accepting a byte array - and then you're using that byte array later, and assuming it will still have the same content. What if the caller to `write()` overwrites the data in the byte array immediately after the method returns? By the time you get to use it, you won't have the right data.

I would extract the `String` from the byte array in your `write` call, and then use that `String` in the call to `write0`.

(I'd also personally use a `Writer` rather than an `OutputStream` - fundamentally you want to deal with text data, not binary data.)